# SMTP host status in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, smtp

Is there a way to check smtp host status in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need that?

As far as I remember if you try to send an email and the SMTP is in no condition of accomplish it, ASP.NET will throw an Exception telling you that. If you don't get an Exception then it means that SMTP is OK.

Comment: I've a sequential workflow which updates some tables in db and sends a email to next person for approval.if smtp is down it is still updating tables but not sending a mail which basically breaks the workflow .So I WANT TO CHECK SMTP STATUS BEFORE MAKING ANY UPDATES TO DATABASE

Comment: So, as I said you should be fine if you don't get an Exception from the .Send() method. If you do get an Exception, you will have to rollback the database transaction.

Comment: i WAS GOING TO DO THAT BUT JUST WANTED TO KNOW IF THERE IS ANY BETTER WAY TO DO IT .Thanks for the reply though